# How to make rest client in tapestry

Tags: rest, client, tapestry

How to make rest client in tapestry.
Not to write just read data from other server in my tapestry application.

I have web server with REST service but I want to read that in my tapestry application

How i can do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [tapestry-resteasy](http://tynamo.org/tapestry-resteasy+guide)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.